# How to make aggregate root smaller

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

## What's going on

I'm developing the internal microservice that handles operation confirmations using one-time passwords. I've decided to create good domain model use event sourcing approach.

## What I have

I have *Confirmation Session* for *Operation* of a certain *Operation Type*. User can add ask *Session* for a *Confirmation Attempt* and specify the *Channel* by which he wants to recieve *Challenge* (one-time password). *Channel* is like SMS, E-Mail, Push, etc.

Here is code excerpt from command handler

```
var session = _sessionFactory.CreateSession(operationType, userId);

var challengeCreationResult = await _challengeProvider.CreateAsync(
    recipient, channelType, session, addOnFields);

if (!challengeCreationResult.IsSuccess)
{
    return OperationResult<AttemptCreationResult>.Error(
        challengeCreationResult.ErrorCode, challengeCreationResult.ErrorMessage);
}

session.AddAttempt(challengeCreationResult.Data);
```

After creating the *Confirmation Attempt* and receiving *Challenge*, *User* is able to submit his response for validation.

```
var session = await _sessionStore.GetAsync(sessionId);

var result = await session.ApplyResponseAsync(response, _responseValidator, actingUserId, operationType);
```

Both `AddAttempt` and `ApplyResponseAsync` result in appropriate events being fired and return operation result to return to *User*.

## What went wrong

I was satisfied with this implementation until I've tried to add business rules that require knowledge of more than one *Confirmation Session*. These are:

1. If user gives five wrong answers for single *Operation Type* within one hour, we need to freeze him for one hour.
2. User is only allowed to request new *Confirmation Attempt* if 30 seconds have passed since last *Confirmation Attempt* that has no correct answer.

## Question

How to implement these rules while keeping aggregate root/services/event handlers small and focused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `UserConfirmation` looks OK as an aggregate, but not the idea of `UserConfirmationHistory`, as it is not recommended to have an aggregate with a lot of children, which would be the case here.

This is a case where the business rule does not naturally fit the aggregate and should be moved up to a domain service, which can operate on a list of `UserConfirmation` instances, supplied by an Application Service.

I mean, I don't like having any infrastructure concerns at all in my domain classes (be they aggregates or services), and fetching a list of `UserConfirmation` entries would require a Query or Repository implementation, which are infrastructure concerns, even if you do abstract them with interfaces.

---

#### What I would do

- Application Service: holds a reference to an `IUserConfirmationRepository` and fetches a list of `UserConfirmation` entries, passing them to a...
- Domain Service: which will receive a list of `UserConfirmation` entries and validate logic spanning multiple aggregates

This way, your business rules are still protected by a domain class.

But **proceed with caution**:

- By doing things this way, you may have just opened a breach. If users of your code are able to create and persist instances of the `UserConfirmation` entity without going through this Domain Service, then they will be able to bypass this invariant;
- Then you should find a way to prevent it. Maybe by making the constructor `internal` in the `UserConfirmation` aggregate, and make it so that the only possible path to create this aggregate is by going through the Domain Service.

---

PS. you mention that things were easier when you just had to do simple INSERTS, but:

- DDD is not an approach for every project. There's a lot of friction early on in projects with DDD, which is only justifiable if your domain is very complex. Then you'll rip benefits down the road;
- If DDD really is the right approach for this project, then you'll really benefit from doing things this way later